# Pack 4 frames inside the window (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

Good day everyone!
I need to place four frames inside the window as shown in the picture, and using the .pack() method.
Now I have 3 frames placed in the window ([picture before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVNRV.png)), and I want to add another one by moving frame f11 to the right. I also attach a picture with how it should look as a result ([picture after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIuvr.png)).

Current part of code:

```
f11 = LabelFrame(current_tab, borderwidth=2, pady=5, relief=GROOVE, labelwidget=lbl_frm_wdgt_founder)
f11.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)

frame_left = Frame(current_tab, borderwidth=0, relief=GROOVE)
frame_left.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

frame_right = LabelFrame(current_tab, labelwidget=lbl_frm_wdgt_arb, borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE)
frame_right.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)

frame_bottom_left = Frame(current_tab, borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE)
# frame_bottom_left.pack(???)
```

Comment: Use `.grid()` if you can.  Otherwise, put the upper frames in a frame, same for the lower frames.

Comment: @acw1668, i had some issues with using .grid() method when i tried to place treeview in 2 columns (column_configure did not help), so i did it all with .pack(). Now i have about 40 widgets, so changing them into .grid() will take a lot of time.. Idea with adding 2 new frames is so awesome! Thank you) But is there more beautiful solution?

Comment: There is not a lot of alternatives. To avoid writing your 40 widgets by hand, you could use one or multiple lists to manipulate them. And with this, you could generate them automatically in a loop and put them one after the other in your list, and at the same time place them in your frame(s), with an increment variable for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to / can't use `grid()`, you can use `tk.Frame()` widgets as generic containers

```
import tkinter as tk  # don't use star imports!
from tkinter import ttk


top_container = tk.Frame(current_tab)
top_container.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.X, side=tk.TOP)
# top container children
frame_left = Frame(
    top_container,
    borderwidth=0,
    relief=tk.GROOVE
)
frame_left.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)

frame_right = LabelFrame(
    top_container,
    labelwidget=lbl_frm_wdgt_arb,
    borderwidth=2,
    relief=tk.GROOVE
)
frame_right.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH)

bottom_container = tk.Frame(current_tab)
bottom_container.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM)
# bottom container children
frame_bottom_left = tk.Frame(
    bottom_container,
    borderwidth=2,
    relief=tk.GROOVE
)
frame_bottom_left.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)

f11 = ttk.LabelFrame(
    bottom_container,
    borderwidth=2,
    pady=5,
    relief=tk.GROOVE,
    labelwidget=lbl_frm_wdgt_founder
)
f11.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH)
```

Since the container frames are packed separately, you can use one on top and another on the bottom

P.S.: Try to avoid `*` star imports - make sure to properly namespace all constants e.g. `tk.LEFT` and classes e.g. `ttk.LabelFrame`